# Converting HTK model to Pocketsphinx

Tags: cmusphinx, htk, handwriting-recognition, pocketsphinx-android

I have a working model built with HTK for online handwriting recognition. Now I want to build another recognition system for Android. After some research I found out that PocketSphinx has a version running on Android OS. Now, what I think of is to convert my HTK model to Sphinx ( or to rebuild it in Sphinx) and then use it with PocketSphinx-on-Android.

First, is there any point that I miss in my plan?

Second, will the converted system (or rebuild with Sphinx) be directly useable in PocketSphinx? In other words, will there be any further conversion/adaptation for a Sphinx model to PocketSphinx?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, what I think of is to convert my HTK model to Sphinx ( or to rebuild it in Sphinx) and then use it with PocketSphinx-on-Android.

Pocketsphinx has more strict format of HMM which is more speech-oriented. For example, all HMMs must have equal number of states. So it might not be easy to convert. It is easier to retrain.

> Second, will the converted system (or rebuild with Sphinx) be directly useable in PocketSphinx? In other words, will there be any further conversion/adaptation for a Sphinx model to PocketSphinx?

Model conversion is not required.

However, there is an issue that pocketsphinx on android allows only voice input, it has no means to input custom features. So you will have to implement that part yourself.